# Copying the neo4j browser visualisations with d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, neo4j, grass

I'm looking to create some visualisations for my neo4j data, and there are some really nice settings in use in the browser that's bundled with it, but there seem less than straightforward to emulate when using d3 - my setup was based on the neo4j visualisation guide at http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/ but this guide doesn't really get you anywhere near what the browser achieves.

For example, I'm looking to emulate:

- multiple curved path between nodes
- paths which end at the edge of the node, and not the center
- graph initialised in a static position (though could probably just hide until d3 presumably fires some event)

I've not seen any official CSS/JS release to get the same effects, so I guess it's assumed the user will code from scratch. Are there any other options for quickly achieving this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's kind of the holy grail.  If you make it, would you share it with us? ;)

In the meantime, sigma.js is a pretty nice library.  Linkurious even released a set of tools on top of it to do even more:

https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js

Comment: I was hoping D3 could solve my problem, as the neo4j browser uses it itself, but Linkurious was next on my list to try out anyway! thanks!